# The likelihood of response variables in variational Bayesian probit regression

Tags: regression, bayesian, probit, variational-bayes

I read the paper *Explaining Variational Approximations (J.T. Ormerod & M.P. Wand)* and there is a part where they explain variational probit regression with auxiliary variable since the posterior density isn't mathematically tractable. So $$y_{i}|\beta_{0}, \ldots , \beta_{k} \sim \operatorname{Ber}\left(\Phi\left(\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{1i}+\cdots + \beta_{k}x_{ki}\right)\right), \qquad 1\le i \le n$$
where the coefficient vector has a normal prior $\beta \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu_{\beta}, \Sigma_{\beta}\right)$. Because the posterior $\pi\left(\beta|y\right)$ isn't available in closed form, they introduce auxiliary variables:
$$
a_{i}|\beta \sim \mathcal{N}\left(x_{i}^{T}\beta, 1\right)
$$
where $x_{i}$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ row of the design matrix $X$. They now say the introduction of auxiliary variables allow them to write
$$
p\left(y_{i}|a_{i}\right) = I\left(a_{i}\ge 0\right)^{y_{i}}I\left(a_{i}<0\right)^{1-y_{i}}, \qquad 1\le i\le n.
$$
I read the paper by *Albert and Chib (1993)* but still don't understand why this is so. My question is $p\left(y_{i}|a_{i}\right)$ is a density function anyways but a product of two indicator variable is either 0 or 1. What is the reasoning behind this?

[1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1198/tast.2010.09058) J. T. Ormerod & M. P. Wand (2010) Explaining Variational Approximations, The American Statistician, 64:2, 140-153, DOI: 10.1198/tast.2010.09058 ([link](http://dx.doi.org/10.1198/tast.2010.09058))

Comment: The solution to this can be found on the wikipedia page for probit regression. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit_model#Gibbs_sampling

Comment: @RustyStatistician I don't see any solution on the wikipedia page... My question is simple. Why is the density either 0 or 1?

Comment: The answer is there and is simple. It's a Bernoulli distribution.

Comment: @RustyStatistician Bernoulli distribution's mass function is not one or zero, Bernoulli random variable is.

Comment: Think about the representation coupled with the latent variables and it will be.

Comment: @RustyStatistician ok, I think I have to admit I'm not smart enough to wrap my head around this. Could you explain why this is so? My thought process is like because $a_{i}$ is given, the indicator variables turn into $1\times 0$ or $0\times 1$ prior to setting $y_{i}$. So the whole density is always $0$ regardless. Am I getting anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Conditional on $a_i,$ $Y_i$ is deterministic. It is assigned $Y_i=1$ if $a_i>0$ and it is assigned $Y_i=0$ if $a_i\leq0$.
Marginally, $Y_i$ is therefore a Bernoulli random variable because $a_i$ has a certain probability p, depending on the independent variables, to be greater than zero, and 1-p to be less than zero

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It’s been a long time but at the time, the confusion was that $0^0$ is undefined. Now my knowledge has matured enough to know the authors assumed $0^0=1$